# jQuery multiple form inputs and multiple sources

Tags: jquery-ui, coldfusion, autocomplete

I have 2 separate form fields where I would like to utilize jQuery's autocomplete function. Currently I have 2 separate functions defined as well as 2 different identifiers for the input for fields. Currently only one works. Here is what my code looks like

form.cfm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "cfc/cfc_auto1.cfc?method=getCustomerNames&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    nameCustomerSearchString: request.term,
                    nameid: request.term,
                    Comp: $('#Comp').val(),
                    maxRows: 25
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#name2").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "cfc/cfc_auto2.cfc?method=getNames&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    nameSearchString: request.term,
                    nameid: request.term,
                    Comp: $('#Comp').val(),
                    maxRows: 25
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```
<form...
<input id="Name" name="Contact" value="" size="70" />
.../form>

<form...
<input id="Name2" name="Contact" value="" size="70" />
.../form>
```

I can show the cfc's but they both work when used by themselves. They are identical except for the query. Auto1.cfc queries a different table then Auto2.cfc.

Comment: Are they both supposed to be passing in the same data?  Do the receive functions both expect to receive {
                nameSearchString: request.term,
        nameid: request.term,
            Comp: $('#Comp').val(),
                maxRows: 25
            }

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dean. No they should be receiving different data from 2 different cfc's. Bear with me.. I am a little green on Jquery/Javascript.

Comment: No I mean the data you are *sending* to the CFCs. Is it supposed ot be the same?

Comment: Also, what is the response(data) function call doing?

Comment: the data is different going to the cfc's. One is looking for customer names, the other is looking for company names. Both are completely independent from each other.

Comment: But if you look at the data you are sending they are both exactly the same. Are these fields and this code on the same page?

Comment: yes.. I have changed the method=getNames to method=getCustomerNames as well as the nameSearchString on the form.cfm as well as the cfc and still get no response. Is there more that I should change?

Comment: The nameSearchString looks the same to me. When you say you "get no response" what do you mean?  Are you looking at the requests in some sort of an HTTP monitor (firebug or something)?  If the requests work fine in the browser when you go to the CFC directly then the problem is likely in the way you are calling them in JavaScript

Comment: Ok... I have edited the code to show what I have now. I have also made the appropriate changes in the cfc. I am using Firebug and am not getting a NET response when I begin typing in the form field.

Comment: Is the request being sent and you're just not getting a response? Or is there no response?

Comment: I guess I am not sure. I get nothing in Firebug when I type in the form. On the autocomplete function that works, I am getting a response back from the cfc. I can only assume that the request isn't being sent.

Comment: Sounds like it.  Do you see any errors in the console?  Are you sure you are loading jQuery and whatever the autocomplete script is?

Comment: at a loss... the autocomplete.js is loading. The other autocomplete function is working fine on the same page. I have looked through other code on the page to see if there was another js conflict but don't see one. I am curious about this: nameid: request.term, Comp: $('#Comp').val(), - is this standard? nameid is in neither of my cfc's.

Comment: No, that's what I was asking about in my first question. That stuff is not standard, that is data that is being passed to the CFCs. Since .ajax() defaults to a GET request, that data will be appended to the URL string. If you look at the request that works in Firebug you'll probably see that there is more on the URL string than you may want.

Comment: You could also look at adding an error() handler to your call to see if you are getting any additional data that may be helpful.  After your success() handler add:  error(xhr, test, type) { alert(test); alert(type); alert(xhr) }

Comment: Ok.. I fixed it and I am not sure how... something was wrong with the form. I looked it over and could not find any difference between the one that worked and the one that didn't. Jason, I really appreciate your help. Hope I can return the favor one day.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  If you ever figure it out you should post an answer to your quesiton

Comment: Well not sure what fixed it. I did remove the nameid and Comp. It still works with them but they were not necessary. It was definitely in the form field. The trick for me realizing that the cfc was not receiving a response.

Comment: Ok... I did find something interesting... I had a <cfparam> tag on the page that was causing it not to work. It had to do with the name. The name was not the same as any arguments in the cfc or a part of the script. I changed the cfparam name and it worked... wierd. This may not have been the original problem but was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see the `name` attribute of the input fields is different from their `id` attribute.

Also the two input fields share the same `name` attribute. Try doing:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
    <input id="Contact1" name="Contact1" value="" size="70" />
    ...
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2">
    <input id="Contact2" name="Contact2" value="" size="70" />
    ...
</form>
```

I think it was trying to get the wrong fields.